# Creating list in View to add to Model's ICollection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a website that allows user to upload recipe

So I have a model class called Recipe and it looks like following

```
[Table("Recipe")]
public class Recipe
{
    public int ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string BakeryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public int EndorsementCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Method> Methods { get; set; }


}
```

and my Ingredient class looks like follow:

```
[Table("Ingredient")]
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Measurement { get; set; }
    public string MeasurementUnit { get; set; }
}
```

And in my View I want to add ingredient dynamically: User click an 'add' button to add another ingredient when she wants to.

My questions are:
How should I create a list in my View for the ingredients and pass it to my Controller's Create method when I submit my form?

And the problem is, as the RecipeID is Autogenerated, I don't know what my RecipeID is going to be while in the View until I save my Recipe in the database table. But how to I pass this RecipeID to each of my Ingredients?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can't save an `Ingredient` until you first save `Recipe`.